# QTAgent32.exe crash whenever I hit a break point

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm working with several automation tests, and have to spend a lot of time stepping through them to find problems.  Lately, with one of the applications we work with, I get a crash error whenever I hit a break point in the code (Using Visual Studios 2012).  The debugging will run along just fine for as long as there are no errors, but as soon as it gets to a break point, wherever it may be, I get that crash error.

I had some of my coworkers run the tests on their machines, and they don't seem to have the same problem.  Obviously this is a fairly significant problem for me.  Anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: It had to do with a patch that was added to VS 2012 that was messing up our code.  Switching to 2013 pretty well solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with a patch that was added to VS 2012 that was messing up our code. Switching to 2013 pretty well solved the problem.